# Amazon Athena scans lots of data when query involves only partitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table on Athena partitioned by `day` (huge table, TB of data). There's no `day` column on the table, at least not explicitly. I would expect that a query like the following:

```
    select max(day) from my_table
```

would scan virtually no data. However, Athena reports that several hundreds of GB are scanned. Any idea why?

===== EDIT 2021-01-14 ===

I've recently bumped on this issue again. It turns out that when the underlying data is parquet then operations on partitions don't consume data. For other data formats that I've tried (including ORC) there is an associated data cost. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Please include table definition. https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/sql/show-create-table.html

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's because the virtual columns defined on the directory names only become "real" when applied to a row of data, which requires reading through the contents. I wonder if storing in an alternate data format (eg Parquet) would be more efficient?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The underlying data is in orc format.

Comment: @Istvan what info from show create table would be most useful?

Comment: @NicolasBusca all, the most important is the table properties and partitioning and bucketing.

Comment: What version of Athena are you using 1 or 2. We did see differences that version 2 reads much more data (than we have seen in version 1)..

Comment: I've tried both 1 and 2, same issue.

Comment: Table is partitioned by `day` (column?), but there's no `day` column on the table. It seems that something is wrong with table definiton. You have to show table definition due to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer for a fact but I guesstimate:

1. Athena just does not have the optimization of looking at the partition names only, when only they are queried. This is clear from its behaviour. So it scans everything.
2. Parquet has min/max for every column whereas ORC does it only if an index is present, AFAIU. Thus for Parquet Athena's query optimizer directs it to look directly at these rollup values, i.e., no scan is performed. It's different for ORC.

Answer (score 0):

I know is a little late to answer this question for you Nicolas but it is important to keep here also some possible solutions.

Unfortunately, this is the way Athena works, Athena will read all data as a tableScan just to list the partitions values.
A possible workaround that works perfectly here is using the metadata of the partition instead of the data information, for example:

Instead of using this syntax:

```
select max(day) from my_table
```

Try to use this syntax:

```
SELECT day FROM my_schema."my_table$partitions" ORDER BY day DESC LIMIT 1
```

This second statement will read just metadata information and returns the same data you need.

Comment: This will not work properly with templated partitions. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html

In case of templated partition $partitions will return whole possible range of partitions.

Comment: Even in case of regular partitions, it might have inconsistency with the actual data, if, for example data was later deleted, but the partition not deleted from the catalog. Or partition was created by some job without actually checking if there's  any relevant data.

Answer (score -1):

It does not depend on the format but on the compression algorithm used. Snappy for ORC mostly & GZIP for parquet. This is what makes the difference

Comment: compression is totally unrelated to the original question